# Stored Procedure fails on tempdb-diskspace when executed by SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-server-2019, tempdb

I developed a bunch of ETL procedures which are executed by an overlaying SQL Script and write Data to separate DB. The Script uses a single Transaction, ensuring we only get complete data.

This script ran fine when I executed it. Now I wanted to automate it, so I put my SQL script inside a Procedure and set up an SQL Agent Job, which is scheduled after working hours so its CPU usage doesn't conflict with other processes. The Procedures use `NOLOCK` / `Isolation Level READ UNCOMMITED`, so no locking can obstruct it and vice versa.

But now the Job fails, telling me tempdb does not have enough space with `error 1101`.

Now my obvious fix is to increase storage, but it seems odd, that the working SQL script turned Procedure runs into an error.

Also: the SQL Agent runs with it own domain user, in case that changes something here.

---

Edit after further debugging:

Executing the script inside of the stored procedure outside of an SP works just fine.

Executing the stored procedure in the replica server of the SQL Server also works.

Comment: Is the job running at a different time than when you ran it manually?  Is it competing for resources in TempDB and auto-growth is off?

Comment: @JonathanFite the disk if full. or rather it was full to begin with when I originally set up the server, because tempdb is on its own disk and I just assigned the entire space to one File per cpu core + log file. Yes, I ran the query in the same idle timespan.

Comment: @SMor I am fully aware, its my coworker who insists and the 3rd party vendor who stipulates `With Nolock`. Not my problem. Just mentioned it, in case it matters for the tempdb